# Como buscar o resumo em português pela API da wikipedia?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para que a API me retorne a string em pt-BR?

```
import wikipedia

pesquisa=wikipedia.summary(keyword)[0:150]
print(pesquisa)
```

Comment: Tentou `wikipedia.set_lang("pt")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Se for o https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/ defina o idioma usando:

```
wikipedia.set_lang("pt")
```

Assim:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang("pt") # Defina antes

pesquisa=wikipedia.summary(keyword)[0:150]
print(pesquisa)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TreasuredTediousNature)</sup>

Note que Wikipédia só tem `pt`, não tem `pt-BR`, ou seja wikipedia em português atende a Portugal e Brasil e provavelmente outros países do mesmo idioma (claro que entendo que existem variações, mas dentro dos proprios artigos as pessoas tentam se adaptar nos textos mesmo)

Comment: Como ficaria isso no codigo?

Comment: @EnzoPortela tá na resposta já, defina antes

Comment: @EnzoPortela o Anderson colocou um link na resposta também, com um exemplo que pega do en.wikipedia e do pt.wikipedia